# Calling action from button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5, I have a controller `MyController` and an action `MyAction`, which takes two integer params: param1 and param2. In my view, I have a button, whose `onclick` function is to be changed using jQuery after a certain event occurs. When the button is pressed, I want it to call the MyAction function, passing the two parameters. Here's my jQuery so far:

```
function DoStuff()
{
    var param1 = 5;
    var param2 = 10;
    $("#my_button").attr('on_click', HELP);
}
```

What goes in place of the `HELP`?

Comment: What you want to set the attribute `on_click` to

Comment: I want to call the MyAction function and pass the two parameters.

Comment: Then do `MyAction(param1, param2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script from the html page you can use (for razor syntax)

```
 function DoStuff()
{
 var param1 = 5;
 var param2 = 10;
 var mvcActionUrl='@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")';
 $("#my_button").attr('on_click', function(){
 $.ajax({
 url:mvcActionUrl,
 data:{param1:param1,param2:param2},
 //Rest of ajax configuration
 });
});

}
```

Otherwise you would need to either extend a parser to replace the razor syntax in .js files or pass the url as a parameter and set the action url from a  tag in the view

Edit: Updated

Comment: Thanks - but how do I pass the two parameters to this?